# Поочередно подставить значения в SQL запрос?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT
  sum(money)
FROM
  `accounts`
WHERE
   date >= (CURDATE()-1) AND date < CURDATE() AND type IN (101,225)
```

Необходимо меняя type, выполнить несколько запросов, например:

```
SELECT
  sum(money)
FROM
  `accounts`
WHERE
  date >= (CURDATE()-1) AND date < CURDATE() AND type IN (353,448)
...
```

Как можно оптимизировать такой запрос?

Comment: А под оптимизацией что имеете в виду? Хотите выполнить одним запросом?

Comment: @cheops да, знаю что можно просто через UNION ALL, но ещё хотелось бы узнать наиболее оптимальные способы.

Comment: это range - тут уже трудно что-то еще сделать.

Comment: Когда речь идет об оптимизации надо начинать с просмотра планов выполнения. Если в плане что то не устраивает - искать пути решения.   А оптимизатор любые "хитрые" способы запросто может привести к одному плану. И план сильно зависит от вашей конкретной таблицы. Ее размера, селективности индексов. И на одной таблице один способ будет быстрее, на другой наоборот медленнее.

Comment: @Mike, я не много работал с оптимизатором MySQL, но успел заметить, что он гораздо чаще строит план дословно тексту запроса, чем оптимизаторы MS SQL и Oracle, например. В этом отношении любые "хитрые" способы с трудом приводятся к одному плану.

Comment: @pegoopik Только вот у меня MySQL строит на join, который вы как раз дали ответом, абсолютно такой же план, как IN. Кроме строк отвечающих за формирование таблицы с числами, конечно. При условии наличия правильного индекса. Так что "сократит обращения к диску" - спорно

Comment: @Mike, про обращения к диску я имел ввиду сравнительно с union all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте на своих данных вариант с JOIN. По крайней мере уменьшит количество обращений к диску(по сравнению с `UNION ALL`).

```
SELECT
  sum(money)
FROM
  `accounts`
  JOIN (
    SELECT 101 as param_type
    UNION ALL SELECT 225
    UNION ALL SELECT 353
    UNION ALL SELECT 448
  ) T ON param_type = type
WHERE
  date >= (CURDATE()-1) AND date < CURDATE()
```